# How to properly install Bootcamp onto internal SATA disk on Mac Pro (2019)

Tags: bootcamp, ssd, mac-pro, sata

I recently got the new Mac Pro (2019) with 256GB SSD. The built-in drive is quite small to hold both macOS and Windows, so I installed a SATA SSD using some DIY-cabling solutions to the internal SATA port as well as a 3D printed case ([here is a good thread for instructions on that](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/that-pegasus-j2i-cage-internal-hdd-mounting.2217197/), I didn't get the J2i because I want SSDs).

Now I want to install Bootcamp onto the new SSD. Here are the methods I've tried (and why they didn't work):

1. Partition with Boot Camp Assistant and ignore the new partition and custom install to the SSD: the Windows installer decided to automatically install to the new partition instead of showing the choose disk screen.
2. Disable Secure Boot, install Windows with a USB install media: installation works fine, however, after installing Windows and the Boot Camp Driver, the system still does not recognize most devices (e.g. keyboard and trackpad doesn't work, they do work in 1). Would call that fail.
3. Install in the new partition in anyway and use software like ghost or Winclone to copy to external disk: for some reasons neither software works. (maybe it needs to be updated?)
4. Install macOS on the SATA disk, than run Bootcamp: The Boot Camp Assistant on the new macOS install also wants to partition the main system disk instead of the SATA disk.
5. Install just like method 3, but using a tool like `ntfs-3g` to manually copy the file to the SSD, then rebuilding the EFI partition with `bcdboot`: works and boot, with keyboard and mouse working, however, some core components like start menu and Microsoft Edge not working.

Which method should I keep investigating in? Or are there is another way that I've missed?

I remembered on the old Mac Pro there is an option to format an entire disk to dedicate to Bootcamp, however, it is not present here.

Comment: Which version of Windows?

Comment: @DavidAnderson Windows 10 1909, the latest one.

Comment: With method 2, can I assume you copied the Windows Support Software to the Windows 10 USB flash drive before booting from the flash drive and installing Windows? Are the keyboard and trackpad wireless. Have you tried a wired mouse?

Comment: @DavidAnderson Yes, I downloaded right off the Mac Pro, and copied it to Windows, then running setup (I even manually loaded some WinPEDrivers). And yeah, wired mouse works (also connecting the Magic Keyboard/Trackpad via lightning cable also works)

Comment: I'm confused...you ask how to *properly* install Bootcamp, then proceed to document all the ways you tried to bodge this together.  The BC utility is not simply "creating a partition" it's actually writing/modifying the partition table so that the Apple Boot Manager (the interface you get when you hold `⌥`) can see and boot from that partition.  Instead of trying to get the bodges to work first, try installing BC first, see what has changed and then try to replicate.

Comment: @Allan: The EFI partition already exists. The BC assistant does not create it. This is where the Windows installation software installs the Windows boot files.

Comment: @DavidAnderson - I *never* said it creates the EFI partition.  I said *it writes/modifies the partition table*.

Comment: @Tom: With method 1, do you remember if you encountered [this window](https://imgur.com/a/w0RFMyz) when installing Windows.

Comment: @DavidAnderson yes, I entered a valid activation code, then it prompts the license agreement screen, I selected agree, and now is where it should show an option for a custom install, however, it moves right into the installing screen.

Comment: @Allan I do want to try to install with BC Assistant, however, it does not support trying to install to the SATA internal SSD, hence this question, and several of my attempt at doing this.

Comment: I ask this question because this is one point where you can enter the shift+F10 key combination to open a Command Prompt window. Also, the Windows installer will have read enough of the Windows Support Software files to have installed the driver to gain access to the 256 GB SSD. My thought was to try installing the Windows boot files in the EFI partition on the 256 GB SSD and install the rest of the Windows files on the SATA SSD. Basically, a modified version of your method 1.

Comment: @DavidAnderson Yeah it can open the command prompt, however, I'm not particularly familiar with operating the Windows Installer, not sure how you would do that with the command prompt.

Comment: You posted using bcdboot which is one command. The some others are diskpart and dism. Are you familiar with either of these? I probably could outline the steps. I can not confirm the steps because my 256 GB SDD is in a 2018 mac mini. I can not not connect to a SATA drive. I best I could do is a VirtualBox simulation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104016/discussion-between-tom-shen-and-david-anderson).